# Most efficient use of Android Libraries for Premium/Lite versisons?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-library

I am trying to create a Lite and Premium version of my application. Instead of creating two versions of the application I am trying to use a Library that each of the two access.

I was wondering if there was a way to do this without having the lite version have access to premium images and xml layouts.

Does anyone have a guide or example where the lite has less content than the premium and where to put the content?

Thanks!

Comment: Generally, library project is used for centralizing common code and resources, if you have images and xml not suppose to be used in Lite project, simply put them into premium project. If you use external build tool like Ant or Maven, they both provide abilities to exclude resources at project build phase.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've already considered this but wouldn't it simpler to have a IAP inside the app that users can use inside to access the premium content?

As for for your question, theres a few blogs I've found on the subject. They all seem to advocate the idea of splitting the lite stuff and premium stuff into separate packages and coding Android to recognise which version the user is using.

http://blog.donnfelker.com/2010/08/05/howto-android-full-and-lite-versions/

http://nexus.zteo.com/blog/2010/10/19/3238/

http://bitowl.wordpress.com/2011/07/06/tutorial-how-to-make-full-and-lite-versions/

Hope this helps

Comment: Those are alright but ideally the lite version should not have the resources from the premium version.