# 2 different versions of same application sharing same Google Play Games application id?

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm changing my application to let me compile it to be used as a free or paid application. I have the free version running yet. It has a lot of achievements and Leaderboards configured on developer console and don't want to rewrite them again. Is it possible for 2 differnet applications in google play share same Google Game Services application id (bind 2 different games to the same application service id)? Or must I create a new application under game serverices in google developer console?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have u looked at this .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319536/most-efficient-use-of-android-libraries-for-premium-lite-versisons

Comment: My questions has nothing to do with this answer. I know how I want to layout my 2 application versions. The question is all about sharing same google game services application in two different applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but according to the documentation it should be possible.

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#application_id), you can click the "Link Another App" button to add more.

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#application_id), you can link up to 20 between Android, iOS, and webApps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. All you have to do is add two different Android linked apps to the application's configuration on the Developer Console.

1. Go to play.google.com/apps/publish
2. Go to the Game Services tab (joystick icon on the left)
3. Click on your game's entry
4. Clicked "Linked Apps"
5. Click "Link another app"
6. Follow the steps to fill in the package name and signing certificate for your second app.

On your second app, make sure to include to set the package name to the one you chose, and make sure to sign it with the certificate whose fingerprint you entered (yes, sounds obvious, but I for one shot myself in the foot with that more than once).

Also, make sure the account you're using to test the game is listed in the Testing section.