# Different Google Play Games user id on android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, google-play-games

I found weird problem. Google Play Games return different user id on different platforms on some gmail accounts.

```
Android: g004520354...
iOS: 108586408195...
```

I have gmail account where is user id the same on both platforms, but we found account (1 month old) with different ids.

Have somebody the same experience?

Comment: Just by the looks of it, the first one seems to be the Google Player Id (used only in Google Play Games) and the second looks like an ordinary Google account id (which would also be the Google Plus id if the user has Google Plus)...
Now why are you getting one and the other on different platforms, that I don't know. Can you provide the relevant code you are using on Android and iOS to get these values?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#d_gather_credentials_for_authentication_and_authorization), that you will have a different client ID for different platform. And according to [Creating multiple client IDs](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#e_optional_creating_multiple_client_ids), if you are creating a game that runs on multiple platforms, you will need to create a separate client ID for each platform (Web, Android, and iOS). To do this, click the **Link another app** button on the **Linked apps** page and repeat the steps starting from the [Create a linked application](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#a_create_a_linked_application) section.

Check also this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547497/2-different-versions-of-same-application-sharing-same-google-play-games-applicat?rq=1) for more information.

Comment: In the documentation you provide links for, the client id is a a key used by the server to call Google APIs.
The question is regarding the user id of the user of the application and as nothing to do with those client ids.